# In the proof (see picture), Similarly line is not aligned. How can I align this line?

Tags: math-mode, align, proof-package

[image: pic]

Code:

```
\begin{proof}
$
\begin{align*}
T(1) &= \theta(1),
\\T(0) &= \theta(1),
\\T(n) &= T(n-1)+T(n-2)+\theta(1)            &&n\geq2
\\T(n) &= T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c                    &&\text{where }c\text{ is a constant.}
\\T(n) &\leq 2T(n-1)+c
\\     &\leq 2[2T(n-2)+c]+c = 2^2T(n-2)+2c+c
\\     &\leq 2^2[2T(n-3)+c]+2c+c = 2^3T(n-3)+2^2c+2c+c
\\     &\vdots
\\     &\leq 2^{n-1}T(1)+2^{n-2}c+2^{n-3}c+\cdots+c
\\     &\lt 2^{n-1}c+2^{n-2}c+2^{n-3}c+\cdots+c+2^{-1}c+\cdots\infty
\\     &= 2^{n-1}c[1+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots\infty]
\\     &= 2^nc
\\T(n) &= O(2^n)
\\\text{Similarly,}
\\T(n)&=\Omega(2^{n/2})
\end{align*}
$
\end{proof}
```

If I put & at the starting of each line then there is too much indentation. Which I do not want. I tried putting & before S then Similarly is aligned with = sign. I tried to google but not sure what keywords should I use and did not find any solution to my problem.

Also, how I bring QED sign at the last line?

Comment: Hi, welcome. First of all, `align*` starts math mode, so don't place it in `$ .. $`.

Comment: Continuing @TorbjørnT. ’s suggestion: (a) The ``\\`` belongs to each of the previous row; (b) Replace `\text{Similarly,}` with `\intertext{Similarly,}`; (c) You don’t really need `&&n\geq2` and `&&\text{where...`. Try `\quad n\geq2` and `\quad \text{where...`. (d) Finally, place `\qedhere` at the end like this `T(n)&=\Omega(2^{n/2}) \qedhere`. Of course, these suggestions work if you have loaded the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Off topic: use `\text{where $c$ is a constant.}`; it is shorter.

Comment: @RuixiZhang, in (d), is the QED symbol pushed to right margin? Not in my test.

Comment: @Sigur The OP must first remove the pair of `$...$` as @TorbjørnT. commented. Then `\qedhere` would work.

Comment: @RuixiZhang The result is not the same in `report` or `amsart` classes. But in both cases it is not on right margin (at least, not in my test).

Comment: @Sigur You’re right. The problem appears to be a bad interaction with point (c) in my comment. Using `\quad` seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the setup of the `align*` environment, don't make it a multi-column affair. Instead, use `\tag*` directives to place the snippets `$n\geq2$` and `where $c$ is a constant` on the far right of the respective lines.

Use a `\shortintertext` directive (provided by the `mathtools` package) to place the string "Similarly,".

Incidentally, what is `+\cdots\infty` supposed to mean?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
  T(1) &= \theta(1) 
\\T(0) &= \theta(1) 
\\T(n) &= T(n-1)+T(n-2)+\theta(1) \tag*{$n\geq2$}
\\T(n) &= T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c         \tag*{where $c$ is a constant}
\\T(n) &\leq 2T(n-1)+c
\\     &\leq 2[2T(n-2)+c]+c = 2^2T(n-2)+2c+c
\\     &\leq 2^2[2T(n-3)+c]+2c+c = 2^3T(n-3)+2^2c+2c+c
\\     &\vdots
\\     &\leq 2^{n-1}T(1)+2^{n-2}c+2^{n-3}c+\cdots+c
\\     &< 2^{n-1}c+2^{n-2}c+2^{n-3}c+\cdots+c+2^{-1}c+\cdots\infty
\\     &= 2^{n-1}c[1+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots\infty]
\\     &= 2^nc
\\T(n) &= O(2^n)
\\ \shortintertext{Similarly,}
T(n)&=\Omega(2^{n/2})\,. \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this layout, using `\intertext`, so ‘Similarly’ is aligned at the left margin. I also use  some commands from `mathtools`, to have  `\vdots` centred w.r.t. the aligned symbols

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
\begin{align*}
T(1) &= \theta(1),
\\T(0) &= \theta(1),
\\T(n) &= T(n-1)+T(n-2)+\theta(1) &&n\geq2
\\T(n) &= T(n-1)+T(n-2)+c &&\text{where }c\text{ is a constant.}
\\T(n) &\leq 2T(n-1)+c
\\ &\leq 2[2T(n-2)+c]+c = \mathrlap{2^2T(n-2)+2c+c}
\\ &\leq 2^2[2T(n-3)+c]+2c+c = 2\mathrlap{^3T(n-3)+2^2c+2c+c}
\\ & \vdotswithin{\leq}\\
 & \leq 2^{n-1}T(1)+2^{n-2}c+2^{n-3}c+\cdots+c
\\ & < \mathrlap{2^{n-1}c+2^{n-2}c+2^{n-3}c+\cdots+c+2^{-1}c+\cdots\infty}
\\ &= 2^{n-1}c[1+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots\infty]
\\ &= 2^nc
\\T(n) &= O(2^n)
\\\intertext{Similarly,}
T(n)&=\Omega(2^{n/2}) & & \qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]